# Create new sheet/tab

Tags: openxml

Here's a short console program that covers the basics of making, copying .xmlx files.  It's a great intro for me to OpenXML and in combination with a few other samples off CodeProject taught me a lot already in the past day:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b28a9f9c-9ad7-4eea-adab-b062883c11e2/formula-cells-in-excel-using-openxml?forum=oxmlsdk

I cannot create a new sheet, a new tab.  Cannot.  Tried for hours.  It even shows that it can be done in a separate function that makes a new workbook.  Try as I might, I have utterly failed at integrating those statements that make extra sheets into the upper function that just opens and reads an existing workbook.  Hours and hours and hours, and I can't get a functioning workbook with more pages than were in the workbook that it copies from.

Can someone help?  Thanks.

Comment: Please read [**Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/290085)

Comment: Posting a [mcve] is the best way to get good help.